# Visual Studio Software Assurance

Tags: visual-studio

Can anyone tell me how to buy Visual Studio Professional with Software Assurance as the links on which I am trying to buy license of visual studio,  I am not getting software assurance ...

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vs-professional-monthly

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can buy it from any E commerce sites they provide these kinds of software

i am giving u a link

https://www.cdw.com/product/Microsoft-Visual-Studio-Professional-with-MSDN-Software-Assurance-1-User/2079790

check it ..

Comment: is there anyway to buy directly from microsoft ?

Comment: no you can buy with MSDN in https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/ but with software assurance.......... there is no option for that ....  please vote up and accept my ans by clicking on the tick